# how to resolve fatal error: 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I had to upgrade my MacOS to Ventura (13.2.1) (M1 Processor)
after that upgration existing Xcode(13.2) not able to launch so I had to upgrade Xcode(14.2), which is compatible to the MacOS(Ventura). Now I can able to run my Xcode, since then the application stopped working. It's not even installed with the emulator.

I had changed arm64 architecture.
and installed pod deintegrate
in terminal sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
and cd ios and did arch -x86_64 pod install

try to run the application from VSCode npx react-native run-ios
and also from the Xcode but I'm getting below error.

fatal error: 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found in React Native

I also tried below solutions.

1. I had added $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React (Recursive) to the Header Search Path under the Build Settings tab in Xcode.
2. Under the node_modules -> react-native-fs -> RNFSManager.m
   #import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>

changed above line with

```
#if __has_include(<React/RCTImageLoader.h>)
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
#else
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
#endif
```

I have tried many solutions related this issue which I found on the internet but, no luck.
I had spent a lot of time, but I didn't get any solution.
Can anyone have any solution to fix this?

Thanks in advance